# (Javascript RESTful get function) How do I query param to get account balance from mapping of accounts

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, mapping

I have a mapping

```
"balances": {
  "1": "1000",
  "2": "2000",
  "3": "3000",
}
```

How do I "get" the balance of for example "2" which is 2000?

right now i have this which manually finds account "2"

```
app.get('/GetBalance/', function (req, res) {
  res.end(JSON.stringify(balances["2"], null, 4));
});
```

how do I find any using params?

For example, i want

/GetBalance/1 to get 1000

/GetBalance/2 to get 2000 and

/GetBalance/3 to get 3000

Answer (score 1):

Use a [route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) :

```
app.get('/GetBalance/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.end(balances[req.params.id]);
});
```

Also there's no need to stringify a string.

Comment: hi sry can i ask how to return "0" if for example i try to get an account that doesnt exist? For example, /GetBalance/4 returns 0. Or is there no way?

Comment: You mean `res.end(balances[req.params.id] || 0)` ?